# vbscript find last line of a text file that does not contain the text "Ack"

Tags: vbscript

I have a log file that I would like to read with vbscript, the file has two lines for each command, e.g. the command itself and following that on the next like an Acknowledgement of the previous line.

So I get:

xxx,xxx,xxx,      ,Blah - some more blah

xxx,xxx,xxx,      ,Blah Ack

I want to go right to the bottom of the log file, and then read back up line by lane until I get to the first line that does not have an "Ack" in it, then put that line in a variable and write it out.

I can get most of it working, I just can figure out how to read back up line by line until I see a line that doesnt have an Ack?

Does anyone have any ideas?

This is what I'm sing to get to the bottom of the file:

```
Const ForReading = 1
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("Y:\Selcall\logs\DEC-20130929.LOG", ForReading)

Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream
  strNextLine = objFile.ReadLine
  If Len(strNextLine) > 0 Then
    strLine = strNextLine
  End If
Loop

objFile.Close

Wscript.Echo strLine
Wscript.Echo Right(strLine, Len(strLine) - 35)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically you can't read a file back to front, so you must read the file from the beginning and remember the last line that doesn't contain the keyword `Ack`:

```
Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream
  strNextLine = objFile.ReadLine
  If InStr(strNextLine, "Ack") = 0 Then strLine = strNextLine
Loop
```

After the loop terminates, the variable `strLine` contains the line you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can't move/read backwards with the FSO's [TextStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/312a5kbt%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) object. You must read the file from top to bottom and store/overwrite each candidate line(s); after the .Close, the storage will contain the last/desired candidate.